# Can not import ViewPagerIndicator library with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-viewpager, android-gradle-plugin, viewpagerindicator

I'm working on a ViewPager project but I can not import the library from Jake Wharton: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

I know that I need to add this code to my build.gradle:

```
repositories {
maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
mavenCentral()
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
        // ...
        compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
        // ...
    }
```

But I got an error when I build the gradle:

```
    Gradle 'ViewPager' project refresh failed: Artifact 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1:library.aar' not found
```

Here's my full grade:

```
    apply plugin: 'android'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

}
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 12):

The instructions at https://bintray.com/populov/maven/com.viewpagerindicator:library/view/release have a solution to the problem:

> In your build.gradle include http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven as a
>   repository ***before*** mavenCentral:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

> Use in your project dependencies as usual:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
}
```

> Why prior to mavenCentral?
>
> Otherwise gradle will look first in mavenCentral, find
>   viewpagerindicator artifact with the same version, but won't find aar
>   package and will report an error, without looking for same artifact
>   with another packaging in other repositories.

Comment: It changed nothing.. still not found.

Comment: I tried both com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar and com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1, still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using `ViewPager Indicator` in studio.All i did was download the .aar file from [viewPagerIndicator aar file](http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1/) and saved it into my libs folder and compiled it using  `compile(name:'library-2.4.1', ext:'aar')` in my application gradle file and also add this  `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added "library-2.4.1.aar" to my libs folder and added your code in my gradle, it still not working when I build it: "Could not find :library-2.4.1:."

Comment: Are you sure you removed all other implementations

Comment: Yes I removed: repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}

Comment: dont remove mavenCentral();

Comment: When I tried your solution, I'm getting warning as *Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: aar*

Answer (score 0):

you can find an aar package here:
https://github.com/Dahlgren/vpi-aar